# Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle при загрузке библиотек

Tags: python, pip

При загрузке любых библиотек через pip выдает такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\curl_cfficacert.pem
```

Не помогла перестановка Питона. Питон версия 3.11. Windows 10

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему.

Comment: Проблема не решена. Прошу помочь.